# Property from file is not found with Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties

I am running into a problem where I can't access a Spring property from my Java code.

Here is the context:

```
<context:property-placeholder ignore-resource-not-found="false"
    location="file:/${setup.properties.directory}/setup.properties"/>
```

The `setup.properties` file looks like this:

```
paymentProvider.x.url=x
```

The code is:

```
SpringContext.INSTANCE.getEnvironment()
                    .getProperty("paymentProvider.x.url");
```

There are no errors during run. However, the result of the code above gives `null`.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: What spring version are you using?Could you please share your pom.xml?If  the property file is in your classpath means follow the link https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/

Comment: @VelNaga, 4.3.1.RELEASE.

Comment: Did you check with @Value annotation way of getting the property?Also do you have this property in classpath or from static path?

Comment: Also follow this link http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/ to load property using different options.

Answer (score 0):

Modify `context:property-placeholder` configuration like:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:setup.properties" />
```

Where you want to access this properties value on that class level use one annotation like:

```
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:setup.properties" })
```

And to read the properties values autowire `Environment` inside that class like:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

And finally you can access like:

```
environment.getRequiredProperty("paymentProvider.x.url");
```

Answer (score 0):

Only

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:/${setup.properties.directory}/setup.properties")
public class SpringContext {
public static final ApplicationContext PROPERTIES_INSTANCE = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
        (SpringContext.class);
}
```

works for me.